# Enhancement suggestion on "How to Ask" page

Tags: feature-request

Currently in "How to Ask" page, SO displays what type of questions can be asked here, what type of questions shouldn't be asked here, do your homework etc. My idea is about to include some examples of good question and bad question (these question(s) can be prepared by experts) and at-least one good question and bad question example can be given on how to ask page,(remaining samples can be given on link to a new page) so that at-least new guys have a some sort of live idea about what type of questions they can ask. Because we see lot of questions like "Write a program to.." "Write a code for me" etc type of questions frequently on SO.

I too agree that page was designed with in a mind that it shouldn't have scrolling, but using ajax we can do like expandable box or something like that.

Is this a bad idea or duplicate idea?

Comment: An example of a good question would have to incorporate technical detail. Unfortunately, there is no way to generalise technical details; there will always be someone who doesn't know a certain programming language/software tool/etc.

Comment: @Asad, that example can be in neutral way like for eg: using if-else or loop etc. These things can be understand by most of the programmers as these concepts are same in all most all languages.

Comment: Right, but a question that asks something extremely general and well known is an example of a bad question, not a good one.

Comment: @Asad, I too agree, it may difficult. But at-least it gives a general idea to poster, if good question is not possible, we can give examples of bad question. So in my question I have added _these question(s) can be prepared by experts_

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this feature request is obsolete (the ask page had several iterations since 2013), and is about a single site.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dual "How To Ask" help pages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215729/282094)