# Dual "How To Ask" help pages

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, help-center

We appear to have two different "How to Ask" help pages:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask
2. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

They both seem to contain help for how to ask a question, and they have some shared content. It seems to me they should be consolidated.

As a side note, both links are used on Stack Overflow. For example, the first link is used on the [Ask Question page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask):

[image: question ask link to how-to-ask]

The second link is used in the question close dialog:

[image: close dialog link to how-to-ask]

Additionally, I see that one of the "How To Ask" pages links to the other one:

[image: one links to the other]

Comment: One of them is to guide new user, I presume (the one with search bar built-in). The other is just general FAQs article.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[One of those pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) is pretty much the same on *every single site on the network*. It's good, general-purpose advice for asking questions. *And* it has a live search box!

[The other one](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is customized for Stack Overflow. It gives examples of questions that might appear on Stack Overflow, offers advice for posting code, etc. The moderators on Stack Overflow can edit it based on feedback to address the issues they see cropping up on Stack Overflow. It is linked to directly from a heavily-used close reason to encourage folks who're struggling to ask good questions to learn from it. It does *not*, however, have a live, working search box.

On most other sites, these two pages are exactly the same (except for the lack of a search box) - but they *could* be modified if need-be to fit the individual needs of each community.

Comment: ah, I see "Pretend you're talking to a busy colleague" so proceed to waste an hour of their time with all your stream of consciousness nonsense?

Comment: Unfortunately, titles are limited to 150 characters - so there's a limit to how much time you can waste there.

Comment: <strike>Unf</strike>Fortunately - there, fixed it for you. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It still seems a bit strange to have it in two places, but now I understand the reasoning.